# Can I access a raw data record by clicking on a cell in an Excel pivot table, using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

[image: example]
What I want to know is if I can access row 4 of the raw data in my example by clicking as shown on the pivot table. Then I could access the Notes column and display it in a messagebox (as I have simulated). The Notes will have text that is too lengthy to include inside the table. The pivot table provides a tooltip message when the cursor moves over a cell but I can't access its text. I am using VBA. Any suggestions very welcome, please.

Comment: I think it would be simplest to put the notes in the field, then use a custom number format of say `;;;"1"` to display the 1 instead (assuming your count is always 1 for a given cell). Then in code you can simply access `activecell.value` to get the actual text - you can also see it in the formula bar.

Comment: Many thanks Rory. I like your answer. I'm almost there, but I am very new to pivot tables. I don't understand "put the notes in the field". When I try to put anything in the Values list (in PivotTable Fields) I am limited to various arithmetical functions eg sum or count. It has to be a number, not text.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed from your post that you knew how to do that. You'll need to add your data to the data model then use Power Pivot and CONCATENATEX in a new measure to return the notes.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance Rory. A little help from "Advanced Analytics with Excel 2019" by Manisha Nigam and my problem is solved!